# Stereo Vision Distance from Disparity Accuracy Measurement Testing

Tags: stereo, stere-image-proc, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

SO I have successfully managed to calibrate my two stereo cameras and thery are running the stereo_image_proc. I am able to view the disparity image stream generated using the image_view node. Before moving onto any mapping I would like to run an experiment on the disparity images in order to check the accuracy and range of the distance by using the values generated by stereo_image_proc node.

I would like to take a series of images at a known of a textured box positioned at a different known distances of a particular range. What would be the best approach for me to calculate the depth? Here are my ideas but I dont know if they are in right or not:

1. Write a C++ subscriber to the stereo_msgs::DisparityImage topic which then takes the disparity image and the f (focal length) and T(baseline) parameters. Converts the disparity image into OpenCV format so that I can calculate the depth for each pixel (disparity) value using the formula z = fT/d and then map the calculated distances on an array or an OpenCV image which can then be indexed to extract a specific distance.

2.Write a C++ Subscriber that attempts at extracting the z cordinate value from either the stereo_msgs::pointcloud or stereo_msgs::pointcloud2  topic for a corresponding x and y coordinate.

Apologies if this has already been discussed but ive looked around and havn't found a solution, or maybe im going at it the completely wrong way. I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62348/stereo-vision-distance-from-disparity-accuracy-measurement-testing/) by [Gaviria R](https://answers.ros.org/users/4637/gaviria-r/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-05-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done something similar.  Instead of using the depth map that is auto-generated, I wrote some of my own image processing looking for markers that I know will be in the image.  Then using the coordinates of center pixel of each marker from both synchronized frames, I calculate the distance using triangulation.

The c++ node that I wrote subscribes the images themselves.

---

Originally posted by [benabruzzo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2641/benabruzzo/) with karma: 79 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0